# php string finding substrings

Tags: php, string, substring

Sorry if this is a newbie question.
Lets say I have this string (the values name and server can change):
Also I forgot to say that I know the length of 'something' .

```
$str='something-name:Jon,server:localhost'
```

Now I must pull the values: 'Jon' and 'localhost' and put them in variables.

What I am doing now:

```
if ((strpos($str, 'something')) !== false){
    $par_name = strpos($str, 'name:');
    if ($par_name !== false){
        $name = substr($n, 20);
    } 
}
```

Now:

```
$name == 'Jon,server:localhost'
```

Instead I need to get only the name and the after the server substring.

```
$name == 'Jon'
$server == 'localhost'
```

I guess I have to find the exact value for the third parameter of substr.
I dont know.

Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this easily with `explode()`. Split the string with comma as the delimiter, split the parts with colon as the delimiter, and grab the part before the colon in both the parts:

```
$str='something-name:Jon,server:localhost';
list($part1, $part2) = explode(',', $str);
list(,$name) = explode(':', $part1);
list(,$server) = explode(':', $part2);
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/54467)

Comment: Yes, indeed, is a way cleaner than mine, but use of list sometimes take from readability. It's not the case here, contrary, here give readability.

Comment: Now I want to give best answer to both, damn.

Comment: @Carondimonio: Mine has demo and is shorter. *cough* :P

Answer (score 2):

**It's just a fast example of how you could achieve this:**

```
$str='something-name:Jon,server:localhost'

$explode = explode(',', $str);

$explodePart1 = explode(':', $explode[0]);

$explodePart2 = explode(':', $explode[1]);

$name = explodePart1[1]
$server = explodePart2[1];
```